# Solve the Greek Computer Puzzle Toy

Tags: code-golf, puzzle-solver

## Solve the Greek Computer Puzzle Toy

There is a small toy of a series of stacked dials -- loosely inspired by the [Antikythera Device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antikythera_mechanism). The puzzle, made by [Project Genius](https://www.projectgeniusinc.com/true-genius-collection), has a series of dials that must be arranged in a particular configuration to win. In this challenge, you will write a function/program to find that solution.
[image: Greek Computer Toy - stacked dials of four rings of numbers in wood]

### The Puzzle

Every dial has 1 or more rings of numbers at 12 radial positions, and they all spin about the same center axis. The top dial has 1 ring, the next dial has 2 rings, then 3 rings, then two dials have 4 rings. Finally, some positions for some rings on some dials are "windows" that let you see the dial below (or the one below that, etc.). The only dial without a window is the very bottom dial.

Once arranged, every radial will have 4 numbers visible (one in each ring), though with the windows, you might be reading any particular number from a higher or a lower dial. You solve the puzzle by arranging the dials so that the numbers in every radial total 42.

There is one solution to the puzzle (see discussion in **Requirements #6**).

### The Code Challenge

#### Source Data

[image: Dial 0 - 1 Ring]
[image: Dial 1 - 2 Rings]
[image: Dial 2 - 3 Rings]
[image: Dial 3 - 4 Rings]
[image: Dial 4 - 4 Rings]

Here is the same data in a text-accessible rendering:

```
Dial 0 Radials:
        0: [3, 0, 0, 0]
        1: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        2: [6, 0, 0, 0]
        3: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        4: [10, 0, 0, 0]
        5: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        6: [7, 0, 0, 0]
        7: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        8: [15, 0, 0, 0]
        9: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        10: [8, 0, 0, 0]
        11: [0, 0, 0, 0]
Dial 1 Radials:
        0: [7, 4, 0, 0]
        1: [3, 0, 0, 0]
        2: [0, 7, 0, 0]
        3: [6, 15, 0, 0]
        4: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        5: [11, 0, 0, 0]
        6: [11, 14, 0, 0]
        7: [6, 0, 0, 0]
        8: [11, 9, 0, 0]
        9: [0, 0, 0, 0]
        10: [6, 12, 0, 0]
        11: [17, 0, 0, 0]
Dial 2 Radials:
        0: [9, 21, 5, 0]
        1: [13, 6, 0, 0]
        2: [9, 15, 10, 0]
        3: [7, 4, 0, 0]
        4: [13, 9, 8, 0]
        5: [21, 18, 0, 0]
        6: [17, 11, 22, 0]
        7: [4, 26, 0, 0]
        8: [5, 14, 16, 0]
        9: [0, 1, 0, 0]
        10: [7, 12, 9, 0]
        11: [8, 0, 0, 0]
Dial 3 Radials:
        0: [7, 9, 3, 1]
        1: [0, 20, 26, 0]
        2: [9, 12, 6, 9]
        3: [0, 3, 0, 0]
        4: [7, 6, 2, 12]
        5: [14, 0, 13, 0]
        6: [11, 14, 9, 6]
        7: [0, 12, 0, 0]
        8: [8, 3, 17, 10]
        9: [0, 8, 19, 0]
        10: [16, 9, 3, 10]
        11: [2, 0, 12, 0]
Dial 4 Radials:
        0: [14, 8, 3, 2]
        1: [11, 9, 3, 5]
        2: [14, 10, 14, 10]
        3: [14, 11, 14, 7]
        4: [11, 12, 21, 16]
        5: [14, 13, 21, 8]
        6: [11, 14, 9, 7]
        7: [14, 15, 9, 8]
        8: [11, 4, 4, 8]
        9: [11, 5, 4, 3]
        10: [14, 6, 6, 4]
        11: [11, 7, 6, 12]
```

#### Requirements

1. Construct the dataset as you see fit.
2. To prevent targeted solutions, your program should suitably randomize the order of the data before traversing it (eg, spin the dials). "Suitably" will obviously have different meanings depending on how you construct your dataset, but the idea is that you randomize the relationship of one dial to the next (do not randomize the order of the radials *within* a dial - who do you think you are... Thanos?).
3. Detect the dial combination that will solve the puzzle
4. No post-hoc fixes; that is, no detecting the orientation of the dials after randomization and then arriving at a known-solution offset from that point. Your solution should, to the view of a reasonable person, mimic the efforts of someone approaching the puzzle for the first time, not knowing the answer beforehand.
5. External libraries are fine, but if you write it for this challenge, count it for this challenge.
6. Output solution as a **pipe-separated list of 12 entries**. These will represent the radial positions of the puzzle, once solved. Each entry should contain a **4-number, comma-separated list** representing the numbers viewable in that radial starting at the center and proceeding outward. An example:

```
#,#,#,#,#|#,#,#,#,#|...etc...
```

Note it will not matter what orientation the puzzle is in (which radial you consider to be "North" or 12 o'clock), as the progression of one radial to the next will be the same once you arrive at a starting point. Therefore, although there is a single solution to the puzzle, it can be stated 12 different ways, each of which would be valid.

> **Example:** A list of 12 single-entry items would be as valid if written `0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11` or `4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,0,1,2,3`, or any of the other 10 lists derived from choosing a unique starting index.

### Scoring

This is a `code-golf` challenge, so smallest program by bytes wins. If possible, report your solution as 2 scores... a **Total Size** score that reflects all of your code (your dataset, randomization, and processing code), and a **Logical Size** that reflects just your processing code (what traverses the suitably randomized dataset). Command line input (ie, off-loading your dataset as an input to the function) should still count as the reported **Total Size** byte count, but obviously would not count to the **Logical Size** score. I am asking for this sort of scoring because I don't want to preclude creativity in lambda-izing the dataset, or elegance in logical traversing.

If you cannot adequately separate and determine a Logical Size score, just report a Total Size score.

Winners will be noted for EACH score -- for whomever has the lowest Total Size, and for whomever has the lowest Logical Size.

Comment: Which is the winning score?  Total or logical size? Or is this 2 competitions in 1?

Comment: Breaking the code into *logical* and *total* parts is impossible to do objectively. Especially golfed code where input, output, etc can be merged with other processing. The best way to push for *logical* code is to make input and output as flexible as is reasonable. This is standard practice already on this site.

Comment: As there is one possible solution, it is possible to precalculate and hardcode it. I don't think there is anything to do here except output a hardcoded solution. Requiring the dials to be randomised simply so that they can be turned to the correct orientation doesn't add much. Insisting that the code actually solve the puzzle would be an unobservable requirement. These are not recommended since it's impossible to draw a clear line between calculating and hardcoding. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11228/15599

Comment: BTW, welcome to the site. This is an interesting challenge I'm not sure yet if it is going to  work out. Before posting another one I recommend you get a feel for the site by answering a few, and post your next one to the Sandbox (see link at top right of your screen.)

Comment: DominicvanEssen - I have clarified the challenge that a winner for each will be chosen, but to Noodle9's point, I have made optional the requirement to report a Logical Size. If you can't do that, just report Total Size.

Comment: I think a better way to rule out hardcoding would be to require that the code works on any puzzle of the given form with a unique solution, and present a few examples at test cases. I doubt that the specific structure of the original puzzle matters much for golfers (other than hardcoding potential), since I'm pretty sure the shortest method will be to try and test all possible rotations.

Comment: Thanks, @LevelRiverSt. I posted on the Sandbox and left it there 3 days. I figured Reqs #2 (randomization) and 4 (no post-hoc fixes) precluded the outputting of the solution without the effort, especially given that "observable" should be implicit in any posted solution (I thought). I know this is a fixed-input, fixed-solution puzzle (it's has a real world analog, after all), but I thought those reqs and the direction to mimic a user new to the puzzle would be enough to close loopholes. Maybe not?

Comment: Yeah unfortunately the sandbox isn't foolproof because traffic can be limited. It looks like you got one upvote there so far and no comments. It's a good idea to wait for several upvotes so you know the post has been viewed and is popular.

Comment: @xnor's suggestion is the way to go imo.  Rubbernilly, even if you cannot find other test cases and provide only the one, simply requiring that the code _theoretically_ work on any valid puzzle input, and allowing flexible IO, is enough to solve all your problems.  It's a very nice challenge as soon as you work out these minor details.

Comment: Requiring very specific input and output formats isn't very fun. Code Golf should be about solving problems, not bureaucracy.

Comment: @user1502040 the reason for specific I/O is to prevent people from abusing too "creative" I/O and also levels the playing field. I posted about this on a codegolf meta post

Comment: @qwr - Please could you post a link to the meta discussion you mention about specific input I/O?  I'd be interested to read others' opinions about the pros & cons...

Comment: @DominicvanEssen I found my opinion post which was not directly on the topic of I/O. https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/24195/17360 here is a general discussion  https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11871/when-to-allow-flexible-input-output